# How to pass list of complex types in query string?

Tags: servicestack

How would I pass a list of complex types in ServiceStack? For example my Request DTO looks like this:

```
//Request DTO
public class Test
{
    public IList<Fund> Funds { get; set; }
}

public class Fund
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public int Percent { get; set; }
}
```

How can I pass the serialized object via HTTP get?

```
http://localhost:49490/api/funds={ ?? }
```

> KeyValueDataContractDeserializer: Error converting to type: Type definitions should start with a '{', expecting serialized type 'Fund', got string starting with: asdf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ServiceStack parses the queryString using the [JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format) this is basically JSON with the CSV-style quotes (i.e. only needs quotes when your value has an escape char).

Although you haven't defined a Custom Route here, in most cases your custom route is the same as your Request DTO which in this case is **Test** not */funds*.

So assuming a custom route looks like:

```
Routes.Add<Test>("/test");
```

You can call your service via a QueryString like:

http://localhost:49490/api/test?Funds=[{Key:Key1,Percent:1},{Key:Key2,Percent:2}]

On a side note Interfaces on DTOs are generally a bad idea, you should consider avoiding (at least limiting) its use at all times.

Comment: Thank you, works perferct! What do you mean exactly with "Interfaces on DTOs are generally a bad idea"? How would you pass/design that in this case?

Comment: I would take the I out of IList - i.e. just have List. If you don't supply concrete types than the few serializers that actually support interfaces have to emit dynamic type info on the wire, unnecessarily bloating the payload and coupling the format to the serializer impl. There's also no good/valid reasons for having interfaces on DTOs.